# JPA Delete parent on @ManyToOne

Tags: java, jpa

[Project on github](https://github.com/AEkman/QuizDesktopApplication/tree/master/src/com/bananpiren/quiz)

I have 3 entities that are connected via each other like this:

```
Quiz

@ManyToOne()
private Quiz quiz;

@ManyToOne()
private QuizQuestions question;
```

I'm trying to delete a quiz using quizId but I am getting:

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`bananpiren`.`quizquestions`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_QUIZQUESTIONS_QUIZ_QUIZID` FOREIGN KEY (`QUIZ_QUIZID`) REFERENCES
>   `quiz` (`QUIZID`))
>   Error Code: 1451

My guess is that JPA doesn't like the foreignkey and works differently from @OneToMany behavior and Cascading doesn't seem to work.

I've tried @ManyToOne

- CascadeType.REMOVE
- CascadeType.Persist

What I want to happen is that when a user deletes a Quiz, all the connected questions and answers should be deleted aswell. Is this possible using only JPA and in a @ManyToOne relationship? If possible how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you want to cascade on the `@OneToMany` relations, not the `@ManyToOne` relations. Cascading on the `@ManyToOne` relations would mean removing a quiz when you're removing an answer to it. So, you will need to define the corresponding `@OneToMany` variables on the `Quiz` class and do `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` there in order to achieve the desired effect.